# Static nested classes in Java

Tags: java, inner-classes, static-members

I'm unsure why this code compiles... quoting the Java tutorials:

> like static class methods, a static nested class cannot refer directly to instance variables or methods defined in its enclosing class — it can use them only through an object reference.

Src: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

```
public class StaticNested {

    private String member;
    private static String staticMember;

    static class StaticNestedClass {
        private void myMethod() {
            System.out.println(staticMember);
            StaticNested nested = new StaticNested();
            System.out.println(nested.member);
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't expect to be able to access member directly, but the code compiles fine.  Am I misunderstanding the Java spec?

Sorry about the formatting, I'm struggling with my browser + post editor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You **aren't** accessing instance members directly.

`staticMember` is accessing a non-instance member, and `nested.member` is accessing one through an object reference.

Comment: What I'm curious about was that I can access `nested.member` without an accessor method...inner classes can access directly private members of the outer class I suppose...

Comment: @cjtightpant: Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 2):

It is correct behavior. What spec meant is that (in your code example) you cant access non-static member field `String member` directly in static nested class like

```
public class StaticNested {

    private String member;
    private static String staticMember;

    static class StaticNestedClass {
        private void myMethod() {
            System.out.println(staticMember);
            System.out.println(member);//<-here you will get compilation error
        }
    }
}
```

but because non-static fields belongs to object of class you can access it with reference to that object like in your code

```
StaticNested nested = new StaticNested();
System.out.println(nested.member);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing it via an instance (not statically).

This does *not* compile:

```
System.out.println(member);
```

Compiler message:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field member